# Xlib: what is the best implementation of GUI digital clock?

Tags: x11, signals, gui, clock, pthreads

I am making an X application which contains a digital clock. The clock displays the current time in the format of "hh:mm". I want to master Xlib, so I want to use only Xlib (no other toolkits).

The clock has to refresh once in a minute. For the refreshment of the clock, I came up with three implementations, but I cannot judge which is the best one. Please tell me which is the best. And, if there are other better implementations, please tell me.

The first implementation refreshes the clock from inside the event loop. The second and third implementations refresh the clock from outside the event loop.

The first implementation is as follows: in the event loop, I use XEventsQueued or XPending to know the number remaining events. If there remains no events, check the current time, and if 1 minute or more passed since the last refreshment, I refresh the clock. If there remains some events, I process other window events.

The second implementation is as follows: I use setitimer with the interval of 1 minute. The signal handler catch SIGALRM and refresh the clock.

The third implementation is as follows: I use pthread. The thread function refreshes the clock and sleep 1 mintes, and does the same thing forever.

The first implementation is the most simple. But I am afraid that it frequently repeats the event loop and consumes the CPU power.

Comment: by the way, why are you studying Xlib? Feels like something you do when you really need to fix a bug in an old graphical framework, so this got my curiousity!

Comment: I have to reasons. The first one is because I want to make a lightweight window manager.   I think using modern toolkits makes the client heavier. (I don't know much about window system, so I may misunderstand.) The second one is just curiosity.

Comment: Modern toolkits do not necessarily tend to make clients heavier; but a window manager has nothing to do with the toolkit the clients use! Curiosity is a great reason :) Just note that X is really dying (slowly, painfully, agonizingly over the last decade), so maybe if you want to learn how to write a window manager, look at Wayland instead? Multiple Linux distros don't even use X by default anymore, their default session, and hence window manager, is wayland-based.

Comment: Because my distro uses X, I am studying Xlib. But it is possible that X will become out-of-date some day. So I think I will need to study Wayland, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first implementation is as follows: in the event loop, I use XEventsQueued or XPending to know the number remaining events. If there remains no events, check the current time, and if 1 minute or more passed since the last refreshment, I refresh the clock. If there remains some events, I process other window events.

This will fail in the rare case there are no events for 1 minute.

> The second implementation is as follows: I use setitimer with the interval of 1 minute. The signal handler catch SIGALRM and refresh the clock.

Perfectly fine.

> The third implementation is as follows: I use pthread. The thread function refreshes the clock and sleep 1 mintes, and does the same thing forever.

Perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was unaware of the fact that XNextEvent blocks the whole procedure.

Answer (score 2):

All methods that Sleep for 1 minute, will drift, because you do other operations, the loop will take a little over 1 minute.

Just waiting one minute, will cause the clock to tick at an arbitrary time within the minute. This will result in a clock that is up to a minute out.

Instead calculate how long it is to the next minute, and set a timer for that long. Or set an event for that time.